# Setting Hidden field value through ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, input, hidden-field

I have 2 hidden fields on a php page. 
1. `<input type="hidden" name="clinic" id="clinic">` 
2. `<input type="hidden" name="flag" id="flag">`

I want to set value of these field though ajax response. when I set these value through ajax response it's not reflected.  
But when I remove `type="hidden"` from these `<input >` tag value is set as required.
 as below 
1. `<input name="clinic" id="clinic">` 
2. `<input name="flag" id="flag">`

I don't know why this is happening? help me.

1st function calls ajax & set response as follows

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("clinic").value=xmlhttp.responseText;   

        }
    }
```

2nd function calls ajax & set response as follows

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            document.getElementById("flag").value=xmlhttp.responseText; 

        }
    }
```

this is my actual ajax request

```
function showAppFlag(leadid,param)
{       
    serviceid = "1";
    if (leadid=="")
    {
        document.getElementById("Flag").value="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {       
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
        {
            document.getElementById('Flag').value= xmlhttp.responseText;
            var flags = document.getElementById('Flag').value;

            if(trim(flags)== "APP" && document.getElementById('cmb_subdispose').value == "APP")
            {
                alert('please select other disposition');
                return;
            }
            else
            {                   
                showClinicFlag(leadid,param);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ctiservice.php?Type=FlagApps&lead_id="+leadid+"&service="+serviceid,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Con you post the code how you are setting the values.

Comment: Can you show your code.?

Comment: I think, I have set values correctly. Please see the edited part

Comment: And what alert(xmlhttp.responsetext) is giving?

Comment: It returns me the the expected value only. only thing is, the value is not getting set to hidden field, I dont know why?

Comment: the code is correct. check if there aren't any elements with the same id in a page.

Comment: I have checked the whole page but names are uniuqe

Answer (score 0):

First try with **type=text**, there will not be issue with type=hidden. Why cant you use like this

```
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) 
            {
                document.getElementById("clinic").value=xmlhttp.responseText;  
                document.getElementById("flag").value=xmlhttp.responseText;          
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please show the ajax code. It will help to resolve. Because i have tried with hidden type, it works fine for me.

Comment: I put original code of ajax request now. Please see if there is any mistake

Comment: Must be Casesensitive issue : please replace with document.getElementById('flag').value= xmlhttp.responseText;

Comment: if it is casecensitive issue then even it should not work with type="text", but it does

Comment: hey Thanks everybody for ur help. I found the reason of this issue.
there were spaces in the response on both sides of the actual output. I still don't know from where these spaces got added. now the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After reading about .value vs setAttribute may be a **properties** vs **attribute** problem. I do not see how or when you're accessing the hidden value but if it's after a form submission then the attribute may not have been set becasue .value sets the current value(property) of the field and you get null. Try using setAttribute.

This is my best guess using the information provided.